# Customize the Django settings.py file depending on the OS

Tags: python, django, operating-system, dropbox

I'm working on a Django project using two different machine, a Windows and a Mac Os X. I have everything synchronized over Dropbox. The problem is that some settings in settings.py are single strings (e.g. the MEDIA_ROOT or the STATIC_ROOT) and not tuples. That means that I can set a proper path for, let's say STATIC_ROOT for only one of the two OS. In the other one of course it won't work.

I was wondering if there exist a way to recognize the OS python is running on and choose the proper  setting through a condition according to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be setting absolute paths in the first place. Use something like `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to get the directory that settings.py is in, then combine it with the specific path piece, e.g.:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')
```

Then, it no longer matters what platform you're running on. FWIW, it's typical to actually store the base path, since it will be needed so often, e.g.:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
...
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
```

Answer (score 6):

The settings.py file is just python, so you can easily switch out statements based on the platform. Use the [`platform` module](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html):

```
import platform

if platform.system() == 'Darwin':
    MEDIA_ROOT = 'something'
else:
    MEDIA_ROOT = 'somethingelse'
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is technically correct and it well addresses my question but I think @Chris Pratt suggested the proper way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12265511/1191416

Comment: @Leonardo: Yup, I saw, and you are quite correct in accepting his!